# How to get attachments message with Graph API

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can't get attachments in message, I try to API [/{message-id}/attachments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/message/attachments) but faild. Please help me!! Thanks.
[image demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1a7p.png)

Comment: Please show us some of your code. Otherwise it's nearly impossible to see what is going wrong.

Comment: I view json by link Graph API with access_token. Not code :)

Answer (score 1):

The message endpoint is page only

> An individual message in Facebook Messenger. This is a Pages-only endpoint.

Use the thread-id instead, but be warned Facebook documentation states that only developers of the app get access to the endpoint

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/thread